# How to retrieve form values after submit to controller in view without using model?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms, entity-framework

in my controller

[HttpPost]

```
public ActionResult Login(string email, string password)
{
    var isValid = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Email == email && m.Password == password);

    if(isValid == null)
    {
         ViewBag.Error = 1;
    }
    else
    {

    }

    return View();
}
```

and view

```
            </div>
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Sign In</button>
            </div>

        </form>
```

i want to retrieve form values after submit to controller i am not using any model and i want without model how can do this ????

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "retrieve form values after submit to controller" ? What is your expected behavior ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can by assigning attribute `name` same as `parameter name` so your view would be like

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "controllername", FormMethod.Post))
{    


            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="email" required>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Sign In</button>
            </div>

}
```

and your action will be like

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login (string password,string email)
    {
       var isValid = db.Users.Any(m => m.Email == email && m.Password == password);

     if(isValid)
   {
       ViewBag.Error = 1;
   }
   else
   {

   }

     return View();
    }
```

and i used `Any` instead of `FirstOrDefault` because it will return `bool` value means if found it will return `true` else `false`